# Why does the object passed to ModelAdmin.save_model not match the Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am overriding the save_model method of my ModelAdmin so I can set some additional fields on the model. However, I keep getting a DoesNotExist exception. I stepped through the code with a debugger and I'm a bit confused.

The model has this field:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='created_by', related_name='%(class)s_creator')
```

In the save_model method when I look at the attributes of the `obj` parameter, I see this:

```
Name:
created_by

Value:
str: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vicki/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518/pysrc/pydevd_resolver.py", line 182, in _getPyDictionary
    attr = getattr(var, n)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 301, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist

Name:
created_by_id

Value:
NoneType: None
```

Where did 'created_by_id' come from, and why does 'created_by'  not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you have used `db_column='created_by'`? Are you dealing with a legacy database? Normally, you would let Django handle the name of the db column. By default, Django will append `_id` to the field name to create the db column name. This is explained in the Django [Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) docs.

On your model instance you can access:

```
`obj.created_by_id` # the primary key of the related User instance
`obj.created_by` # The `User` instance
```

You can't access `obj.created_by` in your method because you haven't assigned a user to it yet. The `created_by_id` value is `None`, and trying to fetch a `User` with primary key `None` naturally raises a `DoesNotExist` exception.

Your `save_model` method should look something like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: No particular reason for the `db_column='created_by'`, I just prefer that. Perhaps I should let Django handle that instead. The information in the question is what the `obj` looks like at the very beginning of the `save_model` method, before I've done anything to it. I want to assign the model's `created_by` field to be `request.user`.

Comment: You can't access `obj.created_by` until it has been assigned a value. I've updated my answer with a suggestion of what your `save_model` method should look like. I recommend that you don't use `db_column` but you can use it here if you want to.

Comment: Ah now that makes sense - I wanted to check if it had already been assigned before I assigned it. I changed my code so it checks the `created_by_id` and if there isn't one, it assigns to `created_by`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, now I understand why you were checking it and getting the error. Glad you've got it working :)